# Trying to read a .csv file from downloads folder of internal storage with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.2

I am trying to read the contents of a `.csv` file which is in my downloads folder of internal storage of my phone. My code looks like this.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    browse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.browse);
    editTextPath = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.path);
    browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select file or dir"), 1);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
            Log.e("Content","In onclick");
        }
    });}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.e("Content","In onactivity");
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        String path = data.getData().getPath();
        Log.e("Pathb",path);
        proImportCSV(new File(data.getData().getPath()));
    }

}

private void proImportCSV(File file) {
    try{
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        CSVReader dataRead = new CSVReader(fr);
        String[] vv = null;
        while((vv = dataRead.readNext())!=null) {
            cv.clear();
        }
        dataRead.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { Log.e("TAG",e.toString());

    }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/primary:Download/12132469_About_0_22092018045225.csv: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I am also sharing a screenshot of my error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wylhf.jpg)

### Update

I made a small change to my previously shared code:

```
private void proImportCSV(File file, Uri uri) {
    try{
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        CSVReader dataRead = new CSVReader(isr);
        String[] vv = null;
        while((vv = dataRead.readNext())!=null) {
            cv.clear();
        }
        dataRead.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { Log.e("TAG",e.toString());

    }
}
```

Here, `uri = data.getData()`. After this change I am getting the following error

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/12132469_About_0_22092018045225.csv: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Also, I have already added this lines of code to my manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am new to asking questions on stack overflow so had no idea about that. Will be careful the next time I post.

Answer (score 2):

You not always can create a working file from a content URI. But you likely don't need it. `new CSVReader(fr);` accepts a `Reader` as a parameter. You can use `InputStreamReader`, created from the `InputStream`, created from the `Uri` using following method:

```
InputStream  inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

where `uri` is `data.getData()`

Comment: Hi, your suggestions helped removing the error `open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)` . But, now I am getting another error `open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)` which is also a java.IO.FileNotFoundException. Can you help with that?

Comment: @ViharBhatt looks like you need the runtime permissions as well (not only to request them in manifest)

Comment: how can I do that? Can you provide some code and info on where in my file and how I should use it? I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @ViharBhatt that should take you around 18 seconds to find using search

Comment: @ Vladyslav Matviienko Thanks buddy. I found the solution for that runtime permissions error. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Worked for me. Appreciate the answer.