# How do I retrieve different types of external files from android device?

Tags: android, file, io, storage, android-external-storage

I have been looking everywhere to find out how to retrieve a file from the external storage and be able to read it. What I want to be able to do is when I open the android app, there will be a button that when pressed I can go into my phones files and select a CSV file. I don't want to get a preselected file though, I want to be able to choose a different file each time. With this file I just want to be able to read from it or download it to internal storage. I'm not very familiar with android IO so hopefully that makes sense.

Here is my code so far which gets a preselected file (just using a preselected file as an example) and am trying to read the file. So far it fails and prints out the Exception block code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String filename = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/example.csv";
Scanner sc = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}

public void buttonOpenFile(View view){

    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    File appSpecificExternalDir = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);

   try {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(appSpecificExternalDir);
       sc.useDelimiter(",");
       while (sc.hasNext()){
           System.out.println(sc.next());
       }
   }catch (Exception e){
       System.out.println("File not valid");
   }

}
}
```

Comment: Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`.

Comment: You do not need any permission to do so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to read a .csv file from downloads folder of internal storage with Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53590041/trying-to-read-a-csv-file-from-downloads-folder-of-internal-storage-with-androi)